# winforms menu as array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I know it most likely possible to access a winforms menu like an array but I am not seeing it in the menu designer of VS2008? What I mean is, my app has a typical menu bar across the top, with multiple items on each drop down. As it is written (I inherited this code), each menu item is a separate name, i.e.

```
myMenuOption1MenuItem
myMenuOption2MenuItem
myMenuOption3MenuItem
myMenuOption4MenuItem
```

etc...

I need the ability to enable or disable (or even hide/unhide) menu options depending on user privileges, for example:

```
For I = 0 to maxIndex
    myMenuOption(I).Enabled = myUser.IsAdministrator
Next
```

Obviously I could set/unset each menu item by name, but for a lot of reasons I'd prefer to use loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolStripMenuItem`s are exposed through `ContextMenuStrip.Items`

```
For Each myItem As ToolStripMenuItem In myContextMenuStrip.Items
    myItem.Enabled = myUser.IsAdministrator
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Each child menu item is in the DropDownItems collection - So you can loop through that (If you are using ToolStripMenuItems and not the older style menus).

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Menu As ToolStripMenuItem In MenuPrincipal.Items

    For Each Item As ToolStripItem In Menu.DropDownItems
        If TypeOf (Item) Is ToolStripMenuItem Then
            AddHandler Item.Click, AddressOf Menu_OnClick
        End If

    Next

Next
```

This way you can access each of the events as follows:

```
Private Sub Menu_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim Frm As Form = GetFormByName(sender.name)
    If sender.Tag = "Modal" Then
        Frm.ShowDialog(Me)
    ElseIf sender.Tag = "Modeless" Then
        Frm.Show(Me)
    Else
        OpenForm(Frm, True)
    End If

End Sub
```